# Bash - Find file with the highest number

Tags: bash, find

I have a list of files in a parent folder with various sub folders. These files can exist in any folder.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
fileabc.txt
file50.txt
file random string 152.png
file 51.jpg
file99.txt
file150.txt
```

I want find the file with the highest number next to the file string in this case it's `file150.txt`. I've tried a few variations of find, sort and tail but nothing is accurate for a range of files. There are also scenarios where file string has a number

```
1file1.txt
1file string.png
1file50.abc
1file 100.abc
```

In the above scenario I would like to get `1file50` as that's the highest number without any spaces.

How can I achieve this in bash?

I've tried this but it only works in some scenarios.

```
dir="/dir/"
find $dir -iname "file*" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Edit: I'm on windows 10 using the developer tools bash. I'm searching for windows files in windows directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, the problem is the subdirs.

```
 find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*1file[0-9]+"  | egrep -o "1file.*" | sort -k 5 -n -r | head -n 1
```

You don't need -iname or -iregex, if all names are lowercase or all are uppercase.

The egrep -o only captures the part from "file" or "1file" and has to be adjusted. For pathological input like "1fileo1file201file400", you have to rethink the problem and are probably faster by hand. :)

For filenames with extensions:

```
find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*file[0-9]+.*"  | egrep -o "file[0-9]*" | head -n 5 
file50
file2
file1
file1
file2
```

Getting sort to start in a word at position doesn't work for me, as expected:

```
find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*file[0-9]+.*"  | egrep -o "file[0-9]*" | sort -r -k [5] 
file75
file7
file6
file50
file50

find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*file[0-9]+.*"  | egrep -o "file[0-9]*" | sort -r -k [5-7] 
file75
file7
file6
file50
file50
```

So we take sed:

```
find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*file[0-9]+.*"  | egrep -i -o "file[0-9]*" | sed 's/file//' | sort -r -n | head -n1 
100
```

We know we subtracted file, so the file should be file100, or FILE100 or FilE100 and so on, but this can be reconstructed with

```
res=100
find -iname "file$res" 
./tmp/A/B/file100
```

or

```
res=$(find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*1file[0-9]+.*"  | egrep -o "1file[0-9]*" | sed 's/1file//' | sort -r -n | head -n1)
find -iname "1file$res*" 
./tmp/A/B/1file250.txt
```

Comment: the file names sometimes can be case insensitive that's why i have `iname`

Comment: This works for files without extension but not for files with extensions.  I didn't realize they it was necessary. The files created via windows/bash are irrelevant. Extensions seems to be the issue. Can you modify it to include extensions?

Comment: Problem was, that I didn't test for subdirs. Now I fixed that.

Comment: With filename extensions is a different questions. You should reduce the problem to core, but if you can't extend the solution to your special case, you have to give the specification up front. Now I have a solution for this, too, but often such changes need a different approach. Omitting the subdirs, however, was my fault, afaik, they where in the question from the start?

Comment: The sub folders were there from the beginning. I added the extensions later on after I realized your solution didn't work with extensions. `find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*file[0-9]+.*"  | egrep -o "file[0-9]*" | sort -k 5 -n -r` this returns all the files not one file with the highest number..

Comment: I can modify it return one file find -regextype egrep -iregex ".*file[0-9]+.*" | egrep -o "file[0-9]*" | sort -k 5 -n -r | head -1 but it doesn't work with file numbers over 100. It takes 99 as the highest number. Similar problem exists for files with 15 and 9. It takes 9 as the highest.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't work out, how the -k option is supposed to work, or if it just isn't possible with sort. With sed, we can cut the filename base away, and reconstruct the file, with an additional find -i ..., if -iname was used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165345/discussion-between-theking963-and-user-unknown).

Answer (score 0):

A bash-specific option: use `set -o globstar` to do the recursion for you, then use the enhanced conditional expression operator `=~` to pull the number out.

With this sample structure:

```
$ tree SomeOrganizedFolder/
SomeOrganizedFolder/
├── Folder1
│   ├── Food1.txt
│   ├── Food2.txt
│   └── SubFolder1
│       └── Food3.jpg
├── Folder2
│   └── Food99.txt
└── Folder3
    └── Food115.txt
```

Run the following commands:

```
highest=-1
for file in SomeOrganizedFolder/**/Food*.txt
do
  if [[ $file =~ Food([0-9]+).* ]]
  then
    [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" -gt "$highest" ]] && highest=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  fi
done
echo $highest
```

The `for` loop selects only files matching the "Food" something + extension pattern, then the internal test looks for numbers that follow the "Food" string before the extension. If there's a number there, it's compared to the currently-highest number.